# Stack Exchange OpenID removal

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I have an OpenID account on: https://openid.stackexchange.com. I wish to completely erase this account. So far I've sent 3(!!) contact form messages regarding the subject. So far I haven't received any reply.

**How do I get my OpenID account completely removed?**

And also I don't know how or who to - but I strongly wish to complain about the lack of response regarding it. Using the form seems as a bad option after the above experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see your message of Wednesday that confirmed the removal of the OpenID account. And I've deleted that account for you.

Of note, Stack Exchange OpenID removal is rarely an urgent issue from our perspective. It usually doesn't hurt to have an account hanging around for an extra day or two. As we wrote on Tuesday, the day you first contacted us:

> I can remove your Stack Exchange OpenID account entirely, but I want to make sure that you're aware of the following:
>
> - This is an irreversible action; we will ***not*** be able to restore your OpenID credentials at a later date.
> - If you use this OpenID account to access third party OpenID enabled services, ***you will not be able to log in to them unless you've added different credentials***, and we can not provide support for them.

So we really want to be sure you know the consequences of removal before we do it.

Comment: I have seen your message and replied with agreement, and later on tried to check that you got my reply.
I understand if it takes a while I was just missing a response that's all.
Sorry if there was misunderstanding from my side.

Thanks! 

post can be closed or erased..

Comment: @Yar: No problem at all. I think I will leave this question up as it could really help other people in the future.